# Как добавить свойство к классу css, используя js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cms, slider

Добрый день! Прошу помощи у знающих js. Имеется cms, которая строит сайты на основе шаблонов,  и предопределенных функций, которые возвращают html+css.  Сделал один хороший человек слайдер, но неудобство в том, что при добавлении его в шаблон сайта, он отображается на всех страницах. Я решил сделать условие при котором проверяется находимся ли мы на главной. Если так то отрабатывает слайдер, иначе скрываем его. Вот проблема в том что я не знаю как правильно его скрыть средствами js. Ниже привожу фрагменты кода. Всем заранее спасибо за помощь!
Эту функцию я вставляю в редактор html и css. Создаю текстовую страницу, и вставляю в функцию id страницы, первым параметром, второй отвечает за вывод заголовка.

```css
.sli {
 width:1200px;
 margin:0 auto; 
}
```

```html
<div class="sli">
   [uss]displaySectionContent(10068037,false)[/uss]
</div>
```

В странице я добавляю картинки для слайдера следующим образом:

```html
<div class="universal_slider">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="/url"><img src="/images/img1" alt="" width="1200" height="600" /></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/url"><img src="/images/img1" alt="" width="1200" height="600" /></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/url"><img src="/images/img1" alt="" width="1200" height="600" /></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Подключаю скрипты

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/scripts/slider/css/unslider.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/slider/js/unslider-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/slider/js/slider.js"></script>
```

Фрагмент кода для запуска работы слайдера:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $('.universal_slider').unslider({ autoplay: true });
});
```

Мой вариант кода с условием требующий доработки:

```js
if (document.location == "http://example.com/about/"){
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $('.universal_slider').unslider({ autoplay: true });
});} else {
 //вот тут надо вставить в класс .universal_slider или .sli свойство display:none 
  //как это можно сделать?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.universal_slider').hide();
```

Comment: Дополните ваш ответ детальным описанием решения проблемы.

Comment: Спасибо все заработало! А как сделать чтобы функция отрабатывала до полной загрузки страницы?

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
if (document.location == "http://example.com/about/") {
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.universal_slider').unslider({ autoplay: true });
    });
} else {
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.universal_slider').css({'display': 'none'});
    });
}
```

Comment: Спасибо все заработало! А как сделать чтобы функция отрабатывала до полной загрузки страницы?

Comment: 1. Можно сделать в css стили display: none, а при загрузке display: block, таким образом по умолчанию страница будет без слайдера, а при инициализации, где необходимо, он будет показываться. 2. Можно элемент со слайдера выводить "чистым" JS - <script>if (...) { document.write('<div class=universal_slider>'); } else { document.write('<div class="hidden">'); }</script><ul> ... Про document.write подробнее - https://learn.javascript.ru/document-write